# Applying specific cell data format using POI

Tags: java, excel-2007, apache-poi

I need to apply specific data format to cell.

```
XSSFCellStyle cellStyle  = workBook.createCellStyle();          
XSSFDataFormat format = workBook.createDataFormat();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("m/d/yy h:mm"));
dataCell.setCellType(1); //String
dataCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

The data is being written but the problem is that the format is applied **only**  when I open excel sheet (in Excel application), click inside the cell with my data.
And then pressing Enter key. 
Only then the format is applied.

How can I apply the format without clicking on every cell?

Comment: You omotted the Java code where you applied the style to the cell.  Please add that to your sample code.

Comment: I add this line (just one line) but I don't think the problem with that, because format is set on cell. But I can see the format only when select the cell end press Enter key.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're setting the cell to be a string. For the most part, cell formatting rules only apply to numeric cells. They don't apply to string cells, those don't get formatted (as they're already formatted to a string!)

```
XSSFCellStyle cellStyle  = workBook.createCellStyle();          
XSSFDataFormat format = workBook.createDataFormat();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("m/d/yy h:mm"));
dataCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

// Set Cell Type not really needed, the setCellValue does it
dataCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
// Set a date value (2012-06-05 08:50)
dataCell.setCellValue(new Date(1338878999635));
```

When you open that in Excel, it ought to be have as expected

Comment: I read the input data from a text file (2/5/2012 12:34), is it necessary to convert data to Date object?

Comment: And why the cell is being formatted when I select it and press enter inside Excel?

Comment: Yes, if you want it to show properly in Excel then you need to set it as a Date not a String

Answer (score 1):

This is how you change the cell format to `Date`.

```
 var workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();

 var sheet = workBook.CreateSheet("Sheet1");

 var dateStyle = workBook.CreateCellStyle();

 var dataFormat = workBook.CreateDataFormat();

 dateStyle.DataFormat = dataFormat.GetFormat("M/D/YYYY");

 row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(item.ModifiedDate.HasValue ?  
           item.ModifiedDate.Value.ToShortDateString(): "");
 row.Cells[0].CellStyle = dateStyle; // This will change your cell to date 
format.
```